# How to add android studio project in same repo on github

Tags: android, git, github

When I uploaded a project on github, it automatically created a new repo with the project name. Now, I want to add another project on my repo. The thing is I want all of my android projects on the same repo. How do I do this? 
The new project I want to add is throwing me error like "remote with selected name already exists".

[image: The github error]

The github error when trying to push.

**EDIT:**

Now when I created a folder in my system and tried uploaded it using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42811365/5520251), some of my projects aren't opening.

[image: It shows like this]

What's this? Any help is widely appreciated!!!

Comment: manually, place them on same folder. commit.

Comment: Good Question. You can add more than one into same git repo right from Android Studio. check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right way todo this. follow these sample steps or you can add it manually

1. Check out git repo and open it in Android Studio.
2. Choose Import Module from File > New
3. Copy your project folder path and past into source directory: click finish that you want to add in existing repo. This will allow you to switch between projects right from Android Studio.
4. Commit and push your code.

Note: Make sure you don't have app with same name. by default it says *app*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload all projects on the same repo. You have to do it manually.
or you can make a folder and then place all your projects inside it.

Comment: So, I'm suppose to make a folder of all android projects & then upload that folder?

Comment: see I've done exactly like you said, some of the projects aren't opening..

Answer (score 0):

You can't create two repositories with the same name. If you want to put all  your projects in same repository, you could either create separate directories under same git or , you could create separate [branches](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-branches).